# Difference Between Constructor Property Promoter and Normal Constructor Arguments

Tags: php

In Magento 2.4.6 I tried to use constructor property promoter along dependency injection with optional arguments but it didn't worked and gave an error. But when I tried to use traditional approach then it worked. If someone could explain why it didn't worked and if there is anything I can do to make it work. PHP Version is 8.1.4

This code works fine

```
private $optional;
public function __construct(
    private MethodInjection $methodInjection,
    Optional $optional = null,
    private array $data = []
) {
    $this->optional = $optional;
}
```

But when I try to use this it doesn't work

```
public function __construct(
    private MethodInjection $methodInjection,
    private Optional $optional = null,
    private array $data = []
) {
    
}`
```

When I try to run setup:upgrade then I get an error saying dependency injection cannot be null.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: @Sitethief "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use null as default value for parameter" I get this error when I use constructor property promoter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "PHP Fatal error: Cannot use null as default value for parameter" tells you everything you need to know.

You told PHP the parameter `$optional` would be an object of the class type `Optional`, but you give it a value of `null`, which is ofcourse neither an object nor of the class type `Optional`.

If you want to be able to use a null value as well you should prefix the type declaration with a question mark like so:

`private ?Optional $optional = null,`

This tells PHP the `$optional` parameter is also nullable, and thus accepts both `null` and objects from the `Optional` class as valid input.